# Vb.net draw horizontal zebra lines

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

How can i draw horizontal zebra lines all over my form?

```
1px Black
1px White
1px Black
1px White
1px Black
1px White
1px Black
1px White
```

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i tried use panel instand bitmap, and the panels width was fixed(when i resized the form the panels stay the same).

Comment: Not sure why someone down-voted this, the question was perfectly clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in this way:

```
Dim Zebra As New Bitmap(Me.Width, Me.Height)
For y = 0 To Zebra.Height - 1
    For x = 0 To Zebra.Width - 1
        If y Mod 2 <> 0 Then
            Zebra.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black)
        Else
            Zebra.SetPixel(x, y, Color.White)
        End If
    Next
Next
Me.BackgroundImage = Zebra
```

(1 px lines)

Comment: Thank You. this is exactly what i wanted to do.